# OrderBy and sort with 2 tables with doctrine, SQL

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 tables:

User:

| id | lastname | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UserA | 2 |
| 2 | UserB | 1 |
| 3 | UserD | 1 |
| 4 | UserC | 2 |

Role:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ROLE_B |
| 2 | ROLE_A |

I would like to order and sort the users with ROLE_B first and alphabeticaly then the rest alphabeticaly, the result should be like this:

| id | lastname | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | UserB | 1 |
| 3 | UserD | 1 |
| 1 | UserA | 2 |
| 4 | UserC | 2 |

I tried with

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
            ->addSelect('roles')
            ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN roles.name = :firstRole THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN orderByRole')
            ->leftJoin('user.roles', 'roles')
            ->setParameters(
                [
                    'firstRole' => EnumRole::ROLE_B
                ]
            )
            ->addOrderBy('orderByRole', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('user.lastname', 'ASC')
        ;
```

But it always orders alphabeticaly by lastname only

If someone know how to do that with doctrine or in SQL, thanks

Comment: Switch the order of the addorderby

Comment: @nbk it doesn't change anything, looks like they don't care about orderByRole

Comment: Then try 

->add('orderBy','orderByRole ASC, last_name ASC').

Comment: @nbk Same result, it's alphabeticaly, idk if it's my CASE because if I comment the orderby user.lastname, it doesn't put my users with ROLE_B in the first place, it's order by id

Comment: What is the actual output of the sql

Comment: Well I found the solution, it was my case I had to invers 0 and 1 
CASE WHEN roles.name = :firstRole THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

@nbk thanks for your help !

Comment: `ASC` (lowest to highest) is ordered by `0,1,2,3,4,5`, etc, which would cause `0` to be listed before `1`. Seems in the original query you wanted `DESC` (highest to lowest) in this instance to indicate a positive match of `roles.name = :firstRole` by ordering it as `1` before `0`.